# Key input restrictions

Tags: java, if-statement

How do you restrict the letter being inputted;

for example I have the code

```
System.out.println("Enter a letter(A,B,C or D):");
letter = input.next().charAt(0);
```

How would I set up an if statement to say if letter does not equal "A" "B" "C" or "D", it will say please input correct letter?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use a `while` loop, so it loops until you get a valid input:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter a letter(A,B,C or D):");
char letter = input.next().charAt(0);

while (letter != 'A' && letter != 'B' && letter != 'C' && letter != 'D') {
    System.out.println("Enter a valid letter(A,B,C or D):");
    letter = input.next().charAt(0);
}

System.out.println(letter);
```

**Output:**

```
Enter a letter(A,B,C or D):
E
Enter a valid letter(A,B,C or D):
A
Valid: A
```

---

But if you just want an `if` conditional, use the same condition of the `while` above:

```
if (letter != 'A' && letter != 'B' && letter != 'C' && letter != 'D') {
    ...
}
```